# Вектор указателей на объекты наследников

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, вектор

У меня такой вопрос: есть базовый  класс A, который содержит только виртуальный метод  печати `Print`. У этого класса есть 2  наследника. Первый B состоит из строки  и в нем определен метод печати для строки. Второй класс D состоит из числа и в нем определен метод печати для числа. Я в мейне создала вектор указателей

`vector<A*> Arr(4)`.

Заполнила его объектами классов наследников. Например, так

```
int k=11;
int p=12;
string n="str"; 
string m="str1";
Arr[0]=new D(11);
Arr[1]=new D(12);
Arr[2]=new B(n);
Arr[3]=new B(m);
```

Теперь в цикле хочу напечатать этот вектор, вызывая каждый раз нужный метод печати. Такая запись не работает

`Arr[i]->Print()`.

Как правильно вызвать метод печати в каждом случае?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
virtual void Print()=0;
};

class B:public A{
public:
string s;
B(string p){
s=p;
}
void Print(){
cout<<s<<endl;
  }
};


class D:public A{
public:
int s;
D(int  p){
s=p;
}
void Print(){
cout<<s<<endl;
  }
};

int main(void){
vector<A*> Arr(4);
int k=11;
int p=12;
string n="str"; 
string m="str1";
Arr[0]=new D(11);
Arr[1]=new D(12);
Arr[2]=new B(n);
Arr[3]=new B(m);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
 Arr[i]->Print();
}

}
```

Comment: нереально сказать не увидев код классов `A, B, D` и их использование

Comment: `Такая запись не работает` это требует расшифровки. Вот, ознакомьтесь с тем, что такое [mcve]. И попробуйте предоставить свой код в таком виде.

Comment: Ваш код не компилируется.

Comment: исправила, забыла конструкторы прописать

Comment: @Lilit5632 и что Вас не устраивает в выводе?

Comment: вывод заработал, допустила глупую ошибку в коде, исправила)код выше работает)

Answer (score 2):

Набил следующий пример - все отлично работает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class D : public A {
public:
    D(int i):m_value(i){};
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << m_value << std::endl;}
private:
    int m_value;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(const std::string& s):m_value(s){};
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << m_value << std::endl;}
private:
    std::string m_value;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> Arr(4);
    Arr[0]=new D(11);
    Arr[1]=new D(12);
    Arr[2]=new B("str");
    Arr[3]=new B("str1");

    for(A* item : Arr) {
        item->print();
    }
}
```

result:

```
11
12
str
str1
```

форма вывода

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < Arr.size(); ++i)
        Arr[i]->print();
```

тоже работает корректно

Comment: почему у вас в классах наследниках функция печати виртуальная?

Comment: @Lilit5632 виртуальность наследуется. Писать `virtual` не обязательно, но и не возбраняется. Лучше, конечно, `override` (c++11).

Comment: Поскольку от `virtual` в классах `B` и `D` тут ничего не зависит, то лучше поправить ответ (с учетом признания ТС в комментарии, что ошибка о которой спрашивалось, реально **не существует**)

Comment: @avp нет смысла править ответ, т.к. надо вопрос закрывать :)